# How to check each element value of a vector testing for two specific values?

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

```
library(tidyverse)
```

I have a vector, called **Drinks_Choice**

```
Drink_Choice <- c(NA, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5, NA)
```

Where 1-5 represets a certain drink type

Once NAs have been ommited I want to be able to test each element of the vector if is has a value of 1 or 5. Initially I tried using a for loop:

```
Drink_Choice %>%
    na.omit()%>%
    if (Drink_Choice == 1|5) {
          cat("Even\n")
        } else {
          cat("Odd\n")
        }
```

As an output I need TRUE (where element is 1 or 5) or FALSE (where element is 2 to 4). Many thanks for any help!!

Comment: @Ventrilocus Care to post as another option in your answer?

Comment: What about when `Drink_Choice` is 3?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind skiping the pipes (%>%), try:

```
na.omit(Drink_Choice) %in% c(1,5)
```

But here with pipes also:

```
Drink_Choice %>% na.omit() %>% (function(x) x %in% c(1,5))
```

Comment: `dplyr` is focused on data frames - and this is a vector. If you're using `%>%` I'd just call it "with pipes" rather than "with `dplyr`". (And pipes, while popularized by `dplyr`, are from the `magrittr` package originally. Plenty of other packages use them too.)

Comment: In the question 3, an odd number, is missing.